# Checking some Regular Expression problems

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I'm given the alphabet $$ \Sigma = {\{a,b}\} $$ 
I tried to write a regular expressions for presenting the following sets:

All strings in $$\Sigma ^ *$$
 with:

a-) number of 2s divisible by 4

b-) exactly one occurrence of 122

c-) exactly one or two 1s

Well I tried to find their solutions, but I am afraid they might be incomplete. So it goes like:

$$ (1^*(22)^*1^*)^* $$ 
$$ 2^*1222^* $$ 
$$ 2^*(1 | 11)2^* $$

respectively for a, b and c parts.

Comment: $ 2^*(1 | 11)2^* $ will reject $121222$

Comment: The previous comment shows that your solution for (c) is not correct. Your solution for (a) matches `22`, which it should not.  Your solution for (b) fails to match `1122`, which does have exactly one occurrence of `122`. What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a). Words with number of $2$s divisible by 4 are words made of subwords that contain exactly 4 $2$s with arbitrary number of $1$s between them.

$$(1^*21^*21^*21^*21^*)^*$$

b). Note that $(21^*+11(1+2)+121)^*$ is the complementary of $122$.
$$(21^*+11(1+2)+121)^*122(21^*+11(1+2)+121)^*$$

c). In a similar concept as in case (a),
$$2^*12^*+2^*12^*12^*$$